# How to refresh jsessionid cookie in Apache/Tomcat loadbalancer

Tags: apache, tomcat, refresh, subdomain, jsessionid

I'm using one Apache HTTPD and multiple Tomcats as the load balancing solution. The session sticky is based on `JSESSIONID` cookie. I have two questions that really need your help.

1) Tomcat version is 7, cookies can be shared with subdomains. The domain looks like this:

- en.mydomain.com
- es.mydomain.com
- it.mydomain.com

Configured in `context.xml`

```xml
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".mydomain.com" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

Meanwhile, we have staging environment that has sub-sub domains, and cookies can also be shared across the domains below:

- en.alpha.mydomain.com
- es.alpha.mydomain.com
- it.alpha.mydomain.com

Configured in `context.xml`:

```xml
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".alpha.mydomain.com" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

But sometimes, `JSESSIONID` cookie can be shared between `en.mydomain.com` and `en.alpha.mydomain.com`, which is **not** expected.

How to resolve this issue? Cookies should **not** be shared in the different level subdomains.

2) I tried to refresh `JSESSIONID` cookie for above question, but failed. In Tomcat JSP:

```java
session.invalidate();
session = request.getSession(true);
out.print(session.getId());
```

`JSESSIONID` cookie is refreshed when directly accessing this Tomcat JSP, but kept the same when accessing its proxy Apache. Should I modify the `mod_proxy` etc. to support the `JSESSIONID` cookie refresh by accessing the Apache URL?

Comment: The second question is related with the first one. Because JSESSIONID cookie is set in apache url, so I won't get the the new session id even using session.invalidate().

Comment: After session.invalidate(), session.isNew() returns true, but session.getId() is the same with the old one. Confused... So if JSESSIONID is in the cookie, this is the servlet mechanism?